ListView in WPF is not showing the ViewModel static data
I am creating a small example to show the enum data using ViewModel on WPF page. But Somehow it is not showing.
public class GameParticipants: IGameParticipants
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public List<string> Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int,string> GameWinner { get; set; }
    public DateTime WinningDate { get; set; }
}

public interface IGameParticipants
{
    List<string> Name { get; set; }
    Dictionary<int, string> GameWinner { get; set; }
    DateTime WinningDate { get; set; }
}

ParticipantsViewModel.cs
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}

public class ParticipantsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string RemoveUnderscore(string text)
    {
        return text.Replace("_", " ");
    }
    public ParticipantsViewModel()
    {
        Participants = new GamesParticipants()
        {
            Name = new List<string>()
            {
                Handball.ToString(),
                Football.ToString(),
                Cricket.ToString(),
                Badminton.ToString(),
                Tennis.ToString(),
                TableTenis.ToString(),
                Rugby.ToString(),
                Boxing.ToString(),

            }
        };
    }

    private GamesParticipants _participants;
    public GamesParticipants Participants
    {
        get { return _participants; }
        set
        {
            _participants = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Participants");
        }
    }
}

MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="Games.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Games"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:ParticipantsViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Participants}" x:Name="lstParticipants" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
      VerticalContentAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=13}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Viewbox>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    
    <Button x:Name="btnRandom" Grid.Row="2" Content="First Game" FontSize="45" Foreground="Green" Cursor="Hand"
            
            Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="btnRandom_Click"></Button>

</Grid>

UI of MainWindow.xaml


What is "the enum data"? Besides that, ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Participants}" requires that the Participants property holds an IEnumerable.

If you want to display the strings that you create in your view model (Handball.ToString(), Football.ToString(), etc.), you should bind to the Name property of the GamesParticipants object:
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Participants.Name}" x:Name="lstParticipants" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
      VerticalContentAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=13}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

